# Bilinear form in finite dimension space

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove that there exist a unique operator $T:V\to V$ such that

$$f(x,y)=g(Tx,y)$$

where $f$ is any bilinear form and $g$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form, and $V$ is a finite dimensional space.

I proved the uniqueness but I dont know how to prove the existence.

Comment: We're missing some information here.  Do we know, for instance, that $g$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form?

Comment: yes, g is a non-degenerate bilinear form.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** fixing a basis for $V$, it suffices to work over $\mathbb{R}^n$. Note that there exist matrices $A$ and $B$ such that
$$ f(x,y) = x^\top \cdot A \cdot y \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(x,y) = x^\top B \cdot y.$$
Now show there exists a matrix $T$ such that $T^\top B = A$.

Answer (score 1):

The form $g$ defines an isomorphism $\hat{g}\colon V\to V^*$ by setting
$$
\hat{g}(x)\colon y\mapsto g(x,y)
$$
Similarly, $f$ defines a linear map $\hat{f}\colon V\to V^*$ by $\hat{f}(x)(y)=f(x,y)$.

Then we get $T\colon V\to V$, $T=\hat{g}^{-1}\circ\hat{f}$, which is the same as saying that $\hat{g}\circ T=\hat{f}$. In particular, for every $x\in V$, we have
$$
\hat{f}(x)=\hat{g}\circ T(x)=\hat{g}(T(x))
$$
and therefore, for every $y\in V$,
$$
\hat{f}(x)(y)=\hat{g}\circ T(x)=\hat{g}(Tx)(y)
$$
which is the same as saying that $f(x,y)=g(Tx,y)$.

---

How do we prove that $\hat{g}$ is an isomorphism? Since $V$ is finite dimensional, it is sufficient to show it is injective. If $\hat{g}(x)=0$, then $g(x,y)=0$, for every $y\in V$. Being $g$ nondegenerate, this implies $x=0$.